# ElasticSearch aggregation return data that do not match query for array field

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am trying to do aggregation on documents which contains categories field. Categories is an array of strings. Sample document:

```
{
  "_index": "test-v11",
  "_type": "_doc",
  "_id": "954961",
  "_version": 4,
  "_score": 1,
  "_source": {
    "id": 954961,
    "categories": [
      "Patent",
      "Trademark"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "id": [
      "954961"
    ],
    "categories": [
      "Patent",
      "Trademark"
    ],
    "categories.keyword": [
      "Patent",
      "Trademark"
    ]
  }
}
```

When I try to aggregate items by categories in the result I see categories that do not match query. My request:

```
POST _search
{
   "aggs":{
      "termBucketAgg":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"categories.keyword",
            "shard_size":65,
            "size":10
         }
      }
   },
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "fields":[
                     "categories"
                  ],
                  "query":"*trade*"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":0
}
```

Response:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "termBucketAgg" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 806,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Patent",
          "doc_count" : 5436
        },
        {
          "key" : "Trademark",
          "doc_count" : 535
        }
        (...)
      ]
    }
  }
```

"Patent" do not match here, but probably I got it in the resposne because I have a document that have both categories. Any idea how to got only categories that match the query?

I am expecting to have in buckets only categories that match query.

**EDIT:** I found a solution. This request return correct data (include part)

```
    POST _search
{
   "aggs":{
      "termBucketAgg":{
         "terms":{
            "field":"categories.keyword",
            "shard_size":65,
            "size":10,
            "include": ".*[cC][oO][nN].*"
         }
      }
   },
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "must":[
            {
               "query_string":{
                  "fields":[
                     "categories"
                  ],
                  "query":"*con*"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "size":0
}
```

Comment: You need to use post_filter on you aggregation result  (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/filter-search-results.html).
the reason you see all the values ​​in your result is because your query will return the entire document. To return only this value it would be necessary to pass the field in nested and to pass by iner_hits but that is not supported for the aggregations.